# Formula should be simple

Tags: excel, sum

im a bit of a rookie to Excel and I cant find an exact answer to my question.

Basically I want to get picture 1(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E5zv.png) to do what picture 2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXJhq.png
) is showing. Its probably a really easy question.

So any value total over 10,000 will be charged at the 25p rate and any value below 10,000 will be charged a the 40p rate.

so cumulatively, one person may have claimed 9999 miles since starting and they put in a new expense claim for 10 miles, I would like the 1 mile to go to the 40p rate and the other 9 to the 25p rate.

What sort of formula would I need?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you please add some code that shows what you have already tried?

Comment: I have tried numerous different simple formulas but cant seem to get any to work how I want it to. Basically what I want it to do (take the pictures for example) when the miles (sum of 49 is pulled from a different tab) I want it to go to the right column, it will split in the example I have showed. so I want 44 to go into the top column and then 4 to go in the second column, and if the new total is below 10,000 I just want it all to stay I in the correct row.

Comment: Can you show some of the formulas you tried??

Answer (score 1):

If the previous cumulative mileage is denoted by `Old`, the additional mileages by `Miles` and the threshold at which the lower rate is payable by `Thold` then consider the following. There are 3 cases:

1. `Old+Miles<=Thold`: All `Miles` paid at the higher rate
2. `Old<Thold<=Old+Miles`: `Miles` split so that `Thold-Old` paid at higher rate and `Miles-(Thold-Old)` at lower rate
3. `Thold<=Old`: All `Miles` paid at lower rate.

`Miles` are paid at the higher rate whenever `Old` is less than `Thold` and the number of miles paid at the higher rate is the lesser of `Miles` (Case 1.) and `Thold-Old` (Case 2.). This could be expressed in Excel-like way as

```
`=IF(Thold-Old>0,IF(Miles<Thold-Old,Miles, Thold-Old),0)`
```

but a much more succinct expression is

```
`=MIN(Miles,MAX(Thold-Old,0))`
```

Both formulae, deliver a correct result in all 3 cases (including a value of zero for case 3.) and so each represents a generally applicable formula for the number of miles to be paid at the higher rate.

Similarly, miles are paid at the lower rate whenever `Old+Miles` exceeds `Thold` and the number paid at this rate is the lesser of `Miles` (Case 3.) and `Miles-(Thold-Old)` (Case 2.). In this case the `IF` expression is:

```
`=IF(Old+Miles>Thold,IF(Miles<Miles-(Thold-Old),Miles,Miles-(Thold-Old)),0)
```

but this can be equivalently written as

```
`=IF(Old+Miles-Thold>0,IF(Miles<Miles+Old-Thold,Miles, Miles+Old-Thold),0)`
```

and I will leave it for you as an exercise to work out the succinct version. The formula(e) deliver a result of 0 for case 1. and so are generally applicable for calculating the miles to be paid at the lower rate.